# Find duplicates on the basis of a condition in sql

Tags: sql

So, I want to find duplicate IDs in a table on the basis of the condition.

I have multiple ids for files with year 2019, 2019, 2020, 2021. There can be possible overlap of ids between the files across years.
I want to find all the duplicate ids present in 2019 year, which are also present in rest of the years.

So if:

| id | year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 |
| 1 | 2020 |
| 1 | 2021 |
| 2 | 2019 |
| 3 | 2019 |
| 4 | 2018 |
| 4 | 2019 |

I want:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |

Note: I only want IDs specific to 2019. If an Id is present in 2018 and 2020, that should go unmatched.

this is what I tried:

```
select  id from table
intersect
select  id from table where year='2019'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your RDMBS ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to grab **all** of the rows where the year is 2019, you can use the very simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE year = '2019'
```

If you exclusively want to return IDs `1` and `4` for this year, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE year = '2019' AND id IN ('1', '4')
```

If instead you want to return the years where there are duplicates you can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT id, year, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE year = '2019'
GROUP BY year
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Note that you'll need to replace `TABLE` with your table name.

Comment: I guess this dos not answer my question. I want to find ids that are present in all the year files as a whole, and also in 2019. If it is not in 2019, but is in other years, ignore it. But if it is in 2019 and other years, show me the id

Comment: This is incorrect as id should not appear in select list -- it is not in group key.

Comment: This is not the answer for the problem, which is also somehow vague because doesn't  states clearly if the id should repeat for all the other years or for at least one other.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY** this: you can achieve exactly what you want by using `EXISTS` and `HAVING` as below:

```
CREATE TABLE #test(id INT,  year INT)
INSERT INTO #test(id, year) VALUES
(1,     2019),
(1,     2020),
(1,     2021),
(2,     2019),
(3,     2019),
(4,     2018),
(4,     2019)

SELECT t.id 
FROM #test t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #test t1 WHERE t.id = t1.id AND t1.year = 2019)
GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(t.id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you formulated correctly the requirements the query would be:

```
select id, year, count(*) 
from table_name tn 
where tn.year = '2019' 
 and exists (select year 
             from table_name tn2 
             where tn2.id = tn.id and tn2.year = '2018') 
 and exists (select year 
             from table_name tn2 
             where tn2.id = tn.id and tn2.year = '2020') 
 and exists (select year 
             from table_name tn2 
             where tn2.id = tn.id and tn2.year = '2021') 
 group by tn.year 
 having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 conditions, 1st is a simple where: year = 2019, second is a condition of group, if group by id, it can be written as having count(*) > 1.

However you can not write sql with both where and having, as where year = 2019 will impact the grouping, only 2019 rows participates the grouping, and all count is 1.

This can be written with with a sub query, to avoid above problem.

```
select id
from table
where id in (select id from table where year = 2019)
group by id
having count(*) > 1
```